# How to open the display from ssh login?

Tags: kubuntu, ssh, remote-login

Is there any way to open the desktop display from terminal(ssh login)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `-X` option to forward graphical applications. People typically forward single applications or the taskbar or panel rather then the entire desktop. For applications such as Firefox people typically "tunnel".

```
ssh -X user@server
```

Then you can

```
startkde &
```

To use Xephyr :

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr
```

Start a Xephyr session

```
# change "1280x1024" to the size you desire
Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x1024 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :1 &
```

Set your $DISPLAY (assuming Xephyr is on :1)

```
DISPLAY=:1.0
```

ssh in to your server and start kde

```
ssh -XfC -c blowfish user@server startkde
```

- -X = forward X
- -f = puts your ssh session into the background
- -C = use compression -c blowfish = use blowfish (I am told this is the fastest)

If you are using ssh, be sure to understand the security risk, and I personally advise you use keys and disable password authentication.

If you want an entire desktop I would suggest FreeNX. FreeNX is both fast and secure.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Answer (score 6):

If you're just talking about running a graphical application  from the terminal, you can specify the `DISPLAY` environment value like so:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gcalctool
```

Or if you want it to persist you can export it to remain part of your bash session:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: Looks like the only works when the display is opened by the same user who is running this command.  Can it be done w/o `su` to the user who is logged into the display?

Answer (score 1):

I use freerdp-x11 that is front-ended by x2goclient and back-ended by x2goserver, if you are connecting to Linux machines, then the connection is established and secured by ssh.

This also enables shadowing.

Alternatively, xtightvncviewer is rather handy.

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt install freerdp-x11
sudo apt install x2goclient
```

For the x2goserver, depending on distro:
https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:ubuntu

You might need to configure such things as this:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Then all you need to do is launch the x2goclient, add in your parameters and pick the desktop type the host is using.
For example, I use:

Parameters:

```
/cert-ignore /sound /multimedia /multimon +fonts
```

when connecting to a Windows terminal server.

The majority of Linux machines are using Lubuntu, which is LXDE, so I pick that and the resolution, the rest works automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit  your question  to expand it with specific details about what you do.

Comment: Done. 987654321 chars